# How to avoid entity tracking on Save with EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am writing a system that has a concept of idempotent operations: If clients give the system an operation id more than once the system will reject those "duplicated" operations immediately.

I want to implement this by storing UUID Primary-Key values in a table in SQL server such that SQL server will just reject duplicated writes, as expected. My problem comes when EF Core tries to be smart about these values and cache them: EF Core will reject the addition of the entity without ever pinging SQL server because it knows there's already a tracked entity with that same PK. This behavior is ideal in most scenarios but in my specific scenario it will become *very* memory-intensive real quick. I don't want this behavior.

This is the code that I'm using to manually trigger the specific error I need to give clients of the system:

```
      Action throwIdempotentOpError = () => {
        throw new ExecutionError("The operation you are trying to perform was already performed, please try again with a new client mutation id");
      };

      if (opsRepo.IdempotentOperations.Local.Any(op => op.ClientMutationId == mutationGuid)) {
        throwIdempotentOpError();
      }

      var operation = new IdempotentOperation {
        ClientMutationId = mutationGuid,
        CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
        UpdatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
        RawDocument = context.Document.OriginalQuery,
        Status = IdempotentOperationStatus.Started
      };

      try {
        opsRepo.IdempotentOperations.Add(operation);
        await opsRepo.SaveChangesAsync();
      } catch (DbUpdateException ex) {
        if (ex.InnerException != null && ex.InnerException.Message.StartsWith("Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_IdempotentOperations'")) {
          throwIdempotentOpError();
        }

        throw;
      }
```

Ideally I would only have to throw the error inside the catch block.

How can I disable that entity tracking behavior on the `.Add` call?

For context: `opsRepo` is a `DbContext`

Comment: EF Core isn't trying to be smart. You're misusing it. A DbContext is a *unit of work* and meant to be short lived. Its very reason to exist is to track any objects added to it. Once you're done with it, it's meant to be disposed. `SaveChanges` will persist all tracked changes. Disposing the DbContext without calling SaveChanges will discard them. That's why DbContext is registered as a *scoped* service, scoped to a single request

Comment: To get into the problem you describe you must keep a DbContext alive for a long time, long enough for a duplicate entity to be added. Which probably means that two different requests ended up using the same DbContext instead of each one using its own. If you want a long-lived cache, why are you using a DbContext *at all*? If you want it for easy mapping you can use a microORM like Dapper

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos you've hit the nail right on the head. I have configured the container to construct the class with this code as a singleton with a scope so I've fallen into this issue by my own design. I'll try fixing that or switching to dapper instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem with cashing added Ids and save them into for example `Redis`, check new ids with cached Ids and prevent to insert duplicate items and reject them. But for solving problem with `DbContext`, you should detach the inserted items like this:

```
...
 try {
        opsRepo.IdempotentOperations.Add(operation);
        await opsRepo.SaveChangesAsync();

        //detached inserted entities
        ClearDbContextState();
 
 } 

...

public void ClearDbContextState()
        {
            var entities = opsRepo.ChangeTracker.Entries<IdempotentOperations>().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added ||
                e.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();

            foreach (var entry in entities)
                entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `IHttpContextAccessor` as a way to scope out the injection of  my `DbContext` implementation, side-stepping the issue @Panagiotis Kanavos commented.